# Revert one git branch to reflect another

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, branching-and-merging, revert

Say I have a `master` branch and a `defect` branch created off `master`. The `defect` branch was adding changes on top of `master` but also the `master` branch was being merged to the `defect` branch in between those changes. When I do `git diff master HEAD` I see specific changes made on top of `master`. However, because these changes are scattered across various commits interleaved with merges from `master`, there is no single commit to which I could revert. I need to create a new commit that will undo all differences between `master` and the `defect` branch so that I can merge the `defect` branch into another (release) branch to undo changes made by that `defect` branch. In theory I could copy all files from `master` to the `defect` branch and commit as a new commit, as that effectively would undo those changes. But how can I achieve that with git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand you correctly, you want to change `defect` so that its contents match `master`. If that is the case, do:

```
git checkout master -b temp 
git reset --soft defect 
git commit -m "Updating defect to reflect master"
git checkout defect
git merge temp
git branch -d temp
```